# Nullable Reference Types when using code with #nullable disabled

Tags: c#, nullable

Why doesn't the compiler warn me in line 3? Actually it is trying convincing me that Id is never null. In line 2 there is a warning.

The problem occurs in NSwag generated classes/DTOs containing the `<auto-generated>` tag which disables nullable (documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts)

**Notice** the `#nullable disable` before the last class

[image]

```
int CalcLength1(MyClass instance) => instance.Id.Length;
int CalcLength2(MyClassNullableId instance) => instance.Id.Length;
int CalcLength3(MyOldClass instance) => instance.Id.Length;

class MyClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

class MyClassNullableId
{
    public string? Id { get; set; }
}

#nullable disable
class MyOldClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `string.Empty` is **not** `null`. So `MyClass.Id` surely is not nullable (actually the default-value is completely pointless for the fact if or if not a type is nullable). So why do you think `MyClass` is in any way different to `MyOldClass`?

Comment: MyOldClass is defined in a "#nullable disable" scope

Comment: but still, `MyClass` is in a nullable context. However `Id` is of type `string`, not `string?`, so why do you think it should produce a nullability-warning here?

Comment: MyClass is fine. It is MyOldClass that is the problem, where the compiler tells me Id is not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Nullable reference types (NRTs) docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts):

> Reference type variables in code compiled in a disabled context are nullable-oblivious. ... However, **the default state of a nullable-oblivious variable is not-null**.

And from [Understand contexts and warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-migration-strategies#understand-contexts-and-warnings):

> Each variable has a default nullable state that depends on its nullability:
>
> - Nullable variables have a default `null-state` of `maybe-null`.
> - Non-nullable variables have a default `null-state` of `not-null`.
> - **Nullable oblivious variables have a default `null-state` of `not-null`**.

Since you have disabled nullable context for `MyOldClass` the default state for it's properties is determined as `not-null` so `MyOldClassInstance.Id.Length` produces no warnings (as for why - I assume that this was done to prevent the false-positives that would come from using libraries not upgraded to use NRTs)

Comment: Thanks. So the documentation says that how it works. But isn't it very confusing? Actually the Id was a bad example, which could be expected to not be null. What if the class contained something optional, then I would say that compiler did a false-positive telling me it is not null. The intention where is that it sometimes is null.

Comment: @Stig yep, the case could be made for such interpretation too. It would be great if there would be a flag enabling treating null-oblivious reference types as `maybe-null`

Comment: This is the case with a REST API generated to classes with NSwag. A developer would believe that a property is never null, even when the OpenAPI contract says it is optional. Bummer!