# How does Visual Studio picks up the current framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-6.0, .net-standard-2.0, multitargeting

I started with a `net6.0` project. And decided to provide `netstandard2.0` as internal nuget output for the older supported builds.

Replaced `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` with `<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>` in the .proj file. Now have this

[image]

The problem though is usage of the nullable reference types. `net6.0` and `netstandard2.0` are using different language versions

[image]

I understand that I would have to do one of these

- Downgrade the language for net6.0
- Create separate projects with certain common files and other separate files
- Use conditional compilation

And I tried the conditional compilation

[image]

And it shows that current active framework is `netstandard2.0`. I was wondering, how to change that? I added symbols in "Conditional compilation symbols" on the project level, for "Debug and net6.0 Custom symbols". And I was able to switch that way. Now, I set the symbols so that `netstandard2.0` is active. I rebuilt and what I see - it compiled for `bin\Debug\net6.0` but there is nothing in `bin\Debug\netstandard2.0`. And also I get error -

> Error  CS8630  Invalid 'nullable' value: 'Enable' for C# 7.3. Please use language version '8.0' or greater.    projectName (net6.0)    C:\DEV\Components\projectName\CSC   1   Active

Not a single file has error inside. All references/packages seem resolving fine. I removed all net6.0-specific pieces in code files. Need some advise here. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In multi-target projects VS allows switching between the targets for intellisense and syntax highlighting - there is dropdown on the top left of the text editor (I use .NET 7 since I don't have .NET 6 installed):

[image]

For the JetBrains Rider users the same is possible by selecting the framework at the bottom of text editor:

[image]

Also in my reproducer I have added the conditional attribute to the `Nullable` element in the .csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0'">
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For only nullable you can do it also inline:

```
<Nullable Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0'">enable</Nullable>
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it hit me. Of course, I needed to condition the `<Nullable` tag in the project. And voila - I get all expected output, nuget, all 9 yards. I totally did not know about the drop-down. The only question **I need** to answer - do I really need net6 and netstandard20. May be just turn it all into netstandard2.0... It is just that project started in .net6 and now it might deemed useful for the older code.

Comment: @T.S. if nullable annotations are deemed important then I would consider having 2 versions since nullable-oblivious libraries result in default null-state of **not-null** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77060023/2501279)